# swift Parsing JSON from URL

Tags: json, swift, parsing, url

How can I parse this JSON?

```
{  
   "telefon":"05538690671"
}
```

my code:

```
    let url = NSURL(string: "http://localhost.192.168.1.40.xip.io:8888/store1.php")

    //fetching the data from the url
    URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: (url as URL?)!, completionHandler: {(data, response, error) -> Void in

        if let jsonObj = try? JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: data!, options: .allowFragments) as? NSDictionary {

            //printing the json in console
            print(jsonObj!.value(forKey: "telefon")!)
```

sorry for my English

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I cleaned things up a bit, drop the NS stuff and protected results with `guard`.

```
let url = URL(string: "http://localhost.192.168.1.40.xip.io:8888/store1.php")!

URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: url) { data, _, _ in
    guard let data = data else { return }
    guard let json = try? JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: data, options: .allowFragments) else { return }
    guard let jsonObj = json as? [String: Any] else { return }

    guard let telefon = jsonObj["telefon"] as? String else { return }

    print(telefon)
}
```

---

A bit more debugging.

```
let url = URL(string: "http://localhost.192.168.1.40.xip.io:8888/store1.php")!

URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: url) { data, _, _ in
    guard let data = data, !data.isEmpty else {
        print("Error: data is nil or empty")
        return
    }

    guard let json = try? JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: data, options: .allowFragments) else {
        print("Error: data contains no JSON")
        return
    }

    guard let jsonObj = json as? [String: Any] else {
        print("Error: JSON is not a dictionary")
        return
    }

    guard let telefon = jsonObj["telefon"] as? String else {
        print("Error: Object has no 'telefon' key")
        return
    }

    print(telefon)
}
```

Comment: sorry, when I'm trace this code jump from dataTask to end of code

Comment: @ÜmitGündüz This means one of the `guard` conditions have failed.

Comment: @ÜmitGündüz I added a new version with more debugging in some of the failure conditions.

Comment: thank you very much for your help but the problem same jump from dataTask to end of code

Comment: @ÜmitGündüz `completionHandler` is an async block. Set a breakpoint on `guard let data=data…`

Answer (score 0):

Use Alamofire (https://github.com/Alamofire/Alamofire) to Fetch the data.

Add Alamofire to your project.

## Custom class to parse

```
    import UIKit
    import Alamofire

    typealias DownloadComplete = () -> ()
    
    class YourClassName {

    private var _telefon: String!
    
    var telefon: String {
            if _telefon == nil {
                _telefon = ""
            }
            return _telefon
        }

    func downloadDetails(completed: @escaping DownloadComplete) {
            let currentURL = URL(string: "http://localhost.192.168.1.40.xip.io:8888/store1.php")!
            Alamofire.request(currentURL).responseJSON { response in
                let result = response.result
            if let dict = result.value as? Dictionary<String, AnyObject> {
                if let telefon = dict["telefon"] as? String {
                self._telefon = telefon
                }
            }
            }
      completed()
    }
}
```